# Colocar cor em Type Animation

Tags: javascript, css, react, animação, tailwind

Olá, estou tentando colocar com em uma parte do texto escrito, porém só consegui colocar cor nele inteiro,

```
export const Title = () => {
    return (
        <TypeAnimation
        sequence={[
            "Developer Front, Back e FullStack.",
            1000,    
            "Developer Front-End.",
            2000,      
            "Developer Back-End.",
            2000,      
            "Developer FullStack.",      
            2000,    
        ]}
        wrapper="div"
        cursor={true}
        repeat={Infinity}
        style={{ fontSize: "1.5rem" }}
        splitBy="words"
        mapText={(text, index) =>
          index % 2 === 0 ? (
            <span key={index}>{text}</span>
          ) : (
            <span key={index} style={{ color: "orange" }}>
              {text}
            </span>
          )
        }
        speed={40}            
        />
    );
};
```

no caso eu queria que o Developer ficasse na cor padrão que ja cetei, e que o orange só afetasse o restante, que é o que fica mudando a todo momento, porém não consegui ver uma forma de implementar.

Comment: Você tem que colocar o texto "Developer" cuja cor você quer mudar dentro de um elemento (frequentemente se usa um `span` para isso, mas o `em` parece ser mais semântico para você) e mudar o estilo desse elemento.

Comment: Pelo componente utilizado ele não tem essa opção, o que pode ser feito é um método para setar essas modificações